# Mixing react code with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have this table with a checkbox on each row to allow the user to select rows. In the head of the table I have a checkbox that is supposed to toggle on/off or the checkboxes in the table.

To achieve this I'm using jquery inside the `componentDidMount` method but I have a strange feeling I'm doing things wrong...that react itself can do this. Since I'm just at the start of the react learning I needed to ask you guys if I can do this a little more elegantly.

Here's my code:

```
class Products extends Component
{
    componentDidMount()
    {
        const dispatch = this.props.dispatch;
        dispatch( asyncGetProducts() );

        // NOT SURE ABOUT FOLLOWING PART
        var self = this;
        $( '.proucts tbody tr' ).click( function() {
            $( this ).find( '.checkbox' ).checkbox( "toggle" );
        } );

        $( '.proucts * .ui.checkbox' ).checkbox( {
            onChecked: function( el ) {
                if( $( this ).attr( 'name' ) == "toggle_select_all" ) {
                    $( '.proucts * .ui.checkbox' ).checkbox( "set checked" );
                }
            },
            onUnchecked: function() {
                if( $( this ).attr( 'name' ) == "toggle_select_all" ) {
                    $( '.proucts * .ui.checkbox' ).checkbox( "set unchecked" );
                }
            }
        } );
    }

    //  ...rest of code
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I feel like you are doing this wrong. Instead of using jQuery to find all elements, you should use the power of React. If you have a list of all products already then go through each model object and have a `boolean` set to true that should render as a checked box. That would be faster than using jQuery.